# Can I set 'UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS' to All Pattern usages?

Tags: java, regex

Can I set `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag to ALL Pattern usage in a single point? something like:

```
Pattern.setDefaultOption(UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

Comment: Interesting question, but I honestly doubt it. Anyway why would you want to do it? Maybe there is better solution to your problem than changing some global setting?

Comment: Have you looked into using reflection to modify potentially helping fields within `Pattern`? Other than that, there doesn't seem to be a provided functionality for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think,
For java.util.regex.Pattern, the default setting for "UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS" is disable, you can only change it when you execute the "Pattern.compile" method providing the "UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS" flag, or you could change this seting via the embedded flag expression. See below:

```
(?idmsuxU-idmsuxU)  Nothing, but turns match flags i d m s u x U on - off
(?idmsux-idmsux:X)      X, as a non-capturing group with the given flags i d m s u x on - off
```

It seems that there is no setting method to change this default behaviour.
Maybe, Specifying this flag may impose a performance penalty.
FYI.